# Elvis 2.2.0 : Input vs Insert mode

Tags: insert-mode, startup, elvis

We can start elvis in input mode using **-i** option.
Also we can start input mode with various commands that specified in help `:help`.

But users call **insert mode** too which can also determined from **h** command `:h`.
Is there any difference between insert mode and input mode in elvis?

Also consider that **-i** option is for startup command line: `elvis -i` which is specified in help: `elvis --help`

*elvis version: 2.2.0*

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: from comments below, the answer was originally posted for the elvis version of vi.

---

I think the `insert` and `input` modes are the same thing.

From the documentation you can see all the vim modes :

```
:h vim-modes

Vim has six BASIC modes:
Normal mode
Visual mode
Select mode
Insert mode
Command-line mode
Ex mode

There are six ADDITIONAL modes.  These are variants of the BASIC modes:
Operator-pending mode
Replace mode
Virtual Replace mode
Insert Normal mode
Insert Visual mode
Insert Select mode
```

There is no input mode here, it should be a second name for the `insert` mode

Also the `-i` flags doesn't seems to do what you say. The documentation says that the `-i` flag start vim another `viminfo` file. (see `:h -i`)

The flag you might want to see is the `-y` : it start vim in "easy" mode. (see `:h -y`)

Comment: I mean the **-i** option. I've got it from `vi --help`; _vi version: 2.2.0_

Comment: Also you can see the _input mode_ in various places like `:help` and `vi --help`.

Comment: I might be mistaken here, but [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi#Distribution) vi version 2.7 is from 1979. Does this mean you actually use software older than 35 years?

Comment: @cbaumhardt, You are right :-D. Of course I use _elvis 2.2.0_ I should search more about it. You are right. I found that my *vi* is a symbolic link to *elvis* maybe they are different in this situation. I should read more.

Comment: Looking at the [elvis help files](https://github.com/mbert/elvis/blob/a648881a79c83f5170404d01e442889fbdf3549a/doc/elvisinp.html) I would say that what is called `insert mode` in Vim is called `input mode` in elvis. Both modes have similar roots, but might differ in certain ways, e.g. with the `-i` flag.

Comment: This proves, beyond any doubt, ... that Elvis is not dead.